# New and delete of native memory across Java threads

Tags: java, memory-leaks, native, valgrind

If I have two Java threads executing in native C++ code and one of them new's a native object, is it OK for the other Java thread to do the delete? Naturally, there are plenty of ways to screw up one thread doing a new and another doing the delete. But is there anything 'extra' because they are Java threads? (Like maybe each Java thread gets a separate native heap, or other such nonsense).

I assume there is nothing special about this case, but Valgrind is telling me that I am definitely leaking that memory and I need to get this nonsense out of my head so I can focus on finding the real problem Valgrind is trying to show me.

All Java threads executing native code see the exact same native heap and there is nothing special about them being Java threads vs threads created from native code. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell without more details.

If your threads are using some sort of publishing protocol like this

- thread 'a' allocates some memory and does some work
- thread 'b' is waiting on a semaphore
- thread 'a' finishes its work and signals the semaphore
- thread 'b' consumes the mememory and deletes it

then things should be OK. (Usually you'd have more than just the two threads.)

If you don't use some synchronization mechanism then the memory needs to have strong thread safety guarantees. Most things in C++ only give weak guarantees.

Comment: Right. I specifically left all the details out. I was just looking for a warm fuzzy that the Java threads didn't introduce any additional complications besides all the usual issues. No one explicitly said that, but I'm taking the silence as confirmation. Thank you for taking the time to reply. This was a bad question; I think I should delete it.